# Is it possible to reuse activex code in any other form such as a Class Library or DLL?

Tags: class, visual-c++, dll, activex, class-library

We all know that ActiveX is no more supported by Microsoft. I have a existing ActiveX code for my functionality. But I don't want to use ActiveX anymore. Is there an alternate way to reuse the ActiveX methods in form of any  class Library or DLL so that I can reuse those functions with minimal changes!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends how you have written your library, but yes, it is possble

Comment: If possible in what way ? Can u give an outline about that

Comment: Can you show some examples of what you want to reuse?